# how to read and compare a part of output string with a stored variable in seleniumIDE

Tags: selenium-ide, control-flow

> 98619664xxxx1::01070:0001:SKIP:0 X

is my output that I see in browser, from the `xpath=//pre[contains(.,'98619664xxxx1::01070:0001:SKIP:0 X')]` and I want to extract only `619664xxxx1` from the output string and verify this with a variable I have set in the test suite of the project.

I have tried the storeText of the output to a variable and then with if condition trying to read the text with my variable.

A part of the log:-

> assertElementPresent on xpath=//pre[contains(.,'98619664xxxx1::01070:0001:SKIP:0 X')] OK
>
> 20.storeText on xpath=//pre[contains(.,'98619664xxxx1::01070:0001:SKIP:0 X')] with value response OK
>
> if on "${response}" == "${Rufnummer1}" Failed:
>   missing ) in parenthetical

Comment: Please provide more readable code in the appropriate format.

Comment: // 19 | assertElementPresent | xpath=//pre[contains(.,'98619664xxxx1::01070:0001:SKIP:0 X')] | | { List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//pre[contains(.,\'98619664xxxx1::01070:0001:SKIP:0 X\')]")); assert(elements.size() > 0); } 

// 20 | storeText | xpath=//pre[contains(.,'98619664xxxx1::01070:0001:SKIP:0 X')] | response | vars.put("response", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//pre[contains(.,\'98619664xxxx1::01070:0001:SKIP:0 X\')]")).getText());

Comment: // 21 | if | "${Rufnummer1}" in "${response}" | | if ((Boolean) js.executeScript("return ('arguments[0]' in 'arguments[1]')", vars.get("response"),vars.get("Rufnummer1"))) {